# Can you initialize a derived class with an instance of a baseclass

Tags: java, polymorphism, derived-class, base-class

By that I mean a baseclass, which was not itself initialised using an instance of the derived class. i.e. lets assume it is not an abstract class.

```
class GeomObj{
  Colour x;
}

class Triangle extends GeomObj{
  largestAngle y;
}

GeomObj u;

//now is the following allowed?Taking into account that u was not initialized using an instance of Triangle in the first place

Triangle v = (Triangle)u;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No because a GeomObj is not a triangle. But the inverse works:

```
Triangle u;
GeomObj v = (GeomObj)u;
```

Comment: It's like with dogs and pubs: each pub (subcalss) is a dog (superclass), but not each dog is a pub. =)

Comment: I was just wondering why it can't be converted like int to double when using typecast, where simply a new object is created with the additional parameters. and thanx for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, you can say that every Triangle is GeomObj, but not every GeomObj is a Triangle. So the compiler won't allow you to do that.